# how to make an mesh lookAt to another mesh in different group

Tags: three.js

I'am working on an project with three.js to render 2 glb files in the scene

i have two 3dObjcets renderd now i want one mesh in a first 3d object to lookAt towards the one mesh in second group.

i tried creating a vector on the other mesh position and made this mesh to lookAt the other one but its not working

```
if (child.name == "Temple_L") {

          var target = occluder.children[1].position
          var a = new THREE.Vector3();
          var positions = a.setFromMatrixPosition(target.matrixWorld)

       child.lookAt(a)

}
```

i want the mesh named child to rotate towards the vector a.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Get the destination object's position in world coordinates with [.getWorldPosition()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldPosition):

```
var worldPos = new THREE.Vector3();
occluder.children[1].getWorldPosition(worldPos);
child.lookAt(worldPos);
```